# How do I select only unique values from a list for coloring?

Tags: json, vega-lite, vega

The vega-lite code at the end considers every instance of the column "c" as a unique value and adds a corresponding separate entry to the legend like so:

[image: vega color all as unique]

I need to have only 3 colors in this case: red, blue and yellow - no combinations such as "blue, red". The decision logic would be 50-50, for example: if "blue" has a value of 3 and "blue, red" has a value of 4, the latter would be split into 2 for blue and 2 for red, totalling 5 (3+2) "blue" and 2 "red". If "blue, red" were 5 it would have 2.5 and 2.5 etc.

---

Here is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red, blue"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "yellow, blue"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue, red"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "average", "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "c", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After performing some transformations like `fold, calculate and filter`, you will be able to achieve the desired result, below in the snippet or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVAmQAQUUgm2pVDQgATnDUKAARMlnAgAL4KDt4uSu6oAOye3gCecIKCbMpBIVYRUSCOsW5oACzJ6LlwQX5q+dHoAEKu8QCMFW6h9YXezXEeIF7otREAupEgmD5IshAAZmw+CHagC4J1qLa+-i1dSmkZWSDjBVAWUAyCRmHoNLJqcAAebHMAFIaYDAiUUAofX5QANZwFIASkCAH5Av9vkwCFpAqhoUYAe4lEgbOhzF1IqsaIJMHAfN47g9nm8YT8-ijvsCwYEAHyBfitbqSNh3JBkMh+CiElYgOY0dIbEDYvJKNg4bwQL6uDHecVwAD6suW4VGSh5bAYOCYKTsIDp8uOGqUyB8gO8TCQxKUcFkUDYajuZDQoEwbDYBJo0s2eJFiosVlVcrNIEe7sFwvW3hQSkwKRwNxAsjYCE5gnyIANpmjgaxwbCCaTKYAjgwZpg6EYaKRs07MsS80KC0aQa5E8nvGmM7ILK5oBYbqBprIyDctlVXCN9ulMspTeFl0A):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2, "c": "red, blue"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 7, "c": "yellow, blue"},
      {"a": "A", "b": 4, "c": "blue, red"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1, "c": "blue"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2, "c": "red"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["red", "blue", "yellow"]},
    {
      "calculate": "indexof(datum.c,datum.key) ? datum.b/2 : datum.b",
      "as": "value"
    },
    {"filter": "indexof(datum.c,datum.key) > -1"},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"field": "value", "op": "sum", "as": "value_sum"}],
       "groupby": ["key", "a"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [{"field": "value_sum"}],
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "key",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": ["blue", "red", "yellow"]}
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly in this example. I will have to adapt and implement it in my actual project and I'll (eventually) comment again to let you know if it worked.